# Apache .htaccess rule to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Please help me convert the following Apache htaccess rules to Nginx

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://192.168.201.112/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://192.168.201.112$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|swf)$ - [F,NC]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration means only `192.168.201.112` can access the resouce which has extsion name `(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|swf)` in this server. You can use the following nginx config:

```
location ~ .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|swf)$ {

    set $hit false;
    if ($http_referer ~ "^http://test1.test.com/.*$"){
        set $hit true;
    }
    if ($http_referer ~ "^http://test1.test.com$"){
        set $hit true;
    }

    if ($hit = false) {
        return 403;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is blocking 192.168.201.112 too. In apache it allows the html file to access the images but blocks direct url.

Comment: Okey its working now. But its blocking everything (including html files in the folder). I want to block only those files with extension jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|swf

Comment: Yep!. Its working. Is it possible to apply this rule to a particular folder, say /test/images/ ?